# Install obs studio 26.1 on debian 9

Tags: debian, software-installation, package-management, obs-studio

Is it possible to accomplish that? I need the latest version in order to be able to use the virtual camera along zoom or similar

I've tried building from source following [instructions](https://obsproject.com/wiki/install-instructions#linux), but had a lot of problems with cmake and qt dependencies

I'm reading about installing from sid but I'm not sure what it has to be done and not breaking my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obs-studio` is available from [Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/install/obs-studio/debian), you can install through `snap` rather than adding Sid repository:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install core
sudo snap install obs-studio
```

[obs-studio instructions](https://snapcraft.io/obs-studio)

Comment: It worked great!! thank you. I didn't find the app in menu (gnome), I had to execute `snap run obs-studio` is this the way to open the app? or is there a graphical way?

Comment: @MatíasCánepa `snap run` is your way to run snap applications.